# Integrating Rhino Security with Asp.net membership providers

Tags: .net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider, rhino, rhino-security

How does [Rhino security](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/01/22/Rhino-Security-Overview-Part-I.aspx) gel with the asp.net membership providers? The reason why I am asking is because AFAIK if I need to use attributes `[Authorize]` then I should be implementing or extending the asp.net membership providers.

In my case as I need more than what asp.net membership provider gives me. Rhino Security is a good fit in this case. But I also need the attribute (and other) features that the framework provides (which in turn eases my pain to build up a good security model for my app).

**Edit: *Rephrasing the question.***

How do I integrate Rhino Security with asp.net membership, so that I can do role/level based authorization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quintin,
The two are separated, but related, frameworks.
ASP.Net membership deals mostly with *authentication*, while Rhino Security deals mostly with *autorization*.

Comment: thanks Oren. I was wondering if people have used Rhino Security in asp.net membership to handle authorization. e.g is this logged in user  allowed to handle this action etc.

Comment: especially since the Role providers in asp.net were too limiting